# Is it a good idea to use the Google CDN for jQuery under HTTP2?

Tags: jquery, performance

Currently my website uses the Google CDN for jquery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I first added it when I was using HTTP1.1 - but now I use HTTP2 - so 
I was wondering if it would be quicker if I copied the jQuery library to my own server so that it can be served over the single HTTP2 connection.

- Its a 32k library
- Doubtless, Googles server will be significantly faster than mine.
- If I get it from Google it will not be served over the single HTTP2 connection (different host)
- It will save a DNS lookup too (serving it from my site)
- The Google version  may be already in the users browser cache (being used by many websites) but since jQuery isn't as popular as it once was - is this still a valid reason for keeping it as-is?

I would imagine the difference, if any, will be small - possibly not noticeable by the user.

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow - see what it's like performance-wise,

Comment: Ok - tested it now. With the Chrome DEV tools open I did 20 refreshes using the Google version and 20 refreshes with the version on my own website. And then took the DOMContentLoaded time from the DEV tools window. Took an average to come up with the time. I repeated this 5 times. Results: Run 1: local=0.849,Google=1.192 Run 2: local=0.874, Google=1.086 Run 3: local=0.885, Google=0.839 Run 4: local=0.797,Google=0.804, Run 5: local=0.771, Google=0.765 So out of five runs two are faster, 1 is slower and two are two are very close. So I think hosting it my self wins out.